# Error in my createQueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query in my repository, this is my function:

```
public function queryActivos()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('af')
            ->where('af.activo = :activo')
            ->setParameter('activo', true);
        return $query;
    }
```

I call this function from my formType:

```
->add('articulosDefectuosos','entity', array(
                'empty_value' => 'SELECCIONE ARTICULO DEFECTUOSO',
                'class'     => 'VentasAlmacenBundle:ArticuloDefectuoso',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => false,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                    return $er->queryActivos();
                },
                'attr'  =>  array(
                    'class' => "browser-default"
                )
            ))
```

This get the next error in the queryBuilder:

```
Expected IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got 'WHERE'
500 Internal Server Error - QueryException
```

Where is the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is missing which data to select and from which entity to select the data. Usually, you would add these missing piece of information by calling the `select()` and `from()` methods of the query builder. However, since you are creating the query builder inside your repository you can use its `createQueryBuilder()` method directly which [adds the missing information automatically](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L83-L84):

```
public function queryActivos()
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('af')
        ->where('af.activo = :activo')
        ->setParameter('activo', true);
    return $queryBuilder;
}
```

see also http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder

Comment: You do not need to call `getRepository()` when you already are inside the repository class.

Comment: Yes, sorry jeje, i have updated my query builder with $this->createQueryBuilder :P